# Appending to xml content Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have this xml file. I just want to append another row to each country tag like below. I want the change to be modifies in existing country_data.xml file

```
**<population>2318921212</population>**
```

**The xml file I have**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>&copy;1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

**This is the code I tried:**

```
import lxml.etree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml', parser=parser)
root = tree.getroot()
root[0][0].append("<population>2318921212</population>")
```

Please help me out guys incase if you know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is `root`?  Where did it come from.? Where is the rest of your code, as just that line of code by itself isn't going to do anything? What result do you get?  In summary...you need to provide a lot more information. in your question if you want an answer that has any real value.  Your best bet is to provide a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am sorry. Now I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ET.SubElement` for each country to get the population into the right spot. 
As a bonus, I have added some extra code to get the formatting of the XML correct.
 There is probably a better way to do this but, at least this method works.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom as md


# Import the XML file
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Define the population values for each country
population_values = {'Liechtenstein': '38137',
                         'Singapore': '5955871',
                            'Panama': '4470596'}

# Insert the population field into each country
for country in root:
    population = ET.SubElement(country, "population")
    population.text = population_values[country.attrib['name']]
    

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Prettify the XML and export the file to "output.xml"
# ---------------------------------------------------------

ET.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write('output.xml', encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```

Thanks to [mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn) for the prettify suggestion

---

**output.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
        <population>38137</population>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
        <population>5955871</population>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W" />
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E" />
        <population>4470596</population>
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: Using the `indent()` function (added in Python 3.9) is a much easier way to prettify. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.indent

Comment: oooh - I might give that a try - thanks

Comment: i have updated it now - thank you